# How to know if what the index is returning is correct?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I currently have this simple function, to see if I am accessing the controller index ().

On my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
        
    $sortOption = $request->input('sortDesc') == 'true' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $sortField = $request->input('sortBy') == 'null' ? 'name' : $request->input('sortBy');

    if (($request->input('filter') != 'null' && $request->input('sortBy') != 'null') ||
        ($request->input('filter') != 'null' && $request->input('sortBy') == 'null')) {
        $carriers = MyModel::orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filter') . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $request->input('filter') . '%')
        ->orderBy($sortField, $sortOption)->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate($request->input('size'));
    }

    if ($request->input('filter') == 'null' && $request->input('sortBy') != 'null') {
        $carriers = MyModel::orderBy($sortField, $sortOption)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate($request->input('size'));
    }

    if ($request->input('filter') == 'null' && $request->input('sortBy') == 'null') {
        $carriers = MyModel::orderBy('status', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate($request->input('size'));
    }

    return response()->json($carriers);
    
}
```

and the route

```
Route::resource('/route/controllerRoute', 'MyController')->middleware('checkPermission:permission_index');
```

and my test:

```
public function testGetListOfExcessCarriers(){
   $response = $this->call('POST', 'controllerRoute.index', array(
        'shortBy'=>'asc',
        'filter'=>'xyz'
        ));
   $response->assertStatus(200);

}
```

The result I get is:
[image]

How can I see the response that is being obtained from that request to the index?

---

I also have this other problem: Because it happens that I am testing that route, but I add a route that does not exist as you will see there however the result is successful. What could it be?

```
 $this->call('GET', 'eASDÑLKQWQ!!!', array(
        'sortBy'=>'asc',
        'sortDesc'=>true,
        'filter'=>''
        ))
        ->assertSuccessful();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#available-assertions).

You could for example assert that you see a certain text in the response:

```
$response->assertSeeText($value);
```

Or that the response contains a certain json value:

```
$response->assertJson(array $data, $strict = false);
```

If you want to see the content of the response, to debug your assertions, you can use:

```
$response->dump();
```

As documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#debugging-responses).

Comment: $data would have to build it as expected by the json?

Comment: well data could be something like ['email' => 'test@test.com']

Comment: because when doing a `dd($ response);`
I do not see the data correct, it is more I receive: `ErrorException: unserialize (): Error at offset 0 of 182358 bytes in /var/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php:250`

Comment: Well, you are doing a unit test, so the response you get is only qualified for the documented assert tests. If you want to see the raw output use $response->dump();

Comment: Ok, if it prints something to me in the console, but it also has the same error, that is, the information I am requesting does not come, is it likely that this request is wrong?

Comment: I think so. Best you do "artisan route:list" and choose the route that you want. Then you put that in your get request like $response = $this->postJson('/route/controllerRoute', array(...));

Comment: I have edited my question, can you support me in that last situation, since I am not doing anything good there :(

Comment: I don't know about this "call" function you are referencing.. the documentation says this for a get request: $response = $this->get('/doesnotexist'); I just saw it seems to be the code in old laravel versions. which version are you using?

Comment: well, look at the docs, there is no "->call" function documented.. try the ->get function i mentioned above. for post try the ->postJson function I mentioned a bit earlier